# rewrite url in htaccsess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how to rewrite this url

its opencart url

`"index.php?route=account/profile"` to this `"profile.php?id=any user id"`

i have tried this first

`RewriteRule ^profile.php$ index.php?route=account/profilex [L]`

and then

`RedirectMatch 301 profile.php(.*) profile.php?id=1/$1`

Answer (score 0):

The following htaccess rule should work:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^index.php?route=account/(.+)$   profile.php?id=$1   [L]`

Comment: even if i have 
index.php?route=account/account 
 index.php?route=account/profilex 
index.php?route=account/profile

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your question.

Comment: i have another pages with these name